# how can i shuffle cubes

Tags: unity-game-engine, shuffle, unityscript, cubes

i have 15 cubes and 1 empty gameobject,i want to shuffle them so they change their position on start of the game. actually i am trying to make the 15 puzzle game. but getting problem when cubes chages their positions they overlap one another.please help me how to solve this issue.

**movement.js**

```
        function Start ()
        {


           ChangePosition();
           AssignPositions();

        }  



        function ChangePosition()
        {

          cube1.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube2.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube3.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube4.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube5.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube6.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube7.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube8.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube9.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube10.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube11.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube12.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube13.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube14.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

           cube15.transform.position = new Vector3(Random.Range (1,4),Random.Range (1,4),10);

        }


    function AssignPositions()
     {
          for (var i = 0; i < cubesPosition.length; ++i)
          cubeGameObjects[i].transform.position = cubesPosition[i];
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Your code shuffles your cubes array, which is array of elements of type Vector3. Which is only a half of manipulations you need to do to solve your problem. After you shuffle that array (which you treat as array of cubes' positions) you need to actually assign these positions to your cubes (game objects). To do this, you need to have a list of your cubes' gameobjects. Something like this:

   ```
   var cubes: Vector3[] = blablabla;
   var cubeGameObjects: GameObject[] = blablabla; //it's up to you how to fill this array

   function ChangePosition() {
     //your code goes here
   }

   function AssignPositions() {
     for (var i = 0; i < cubes.length; ++i)
         cubeGameObjects[i].transform.position = cubes[i];
   }

   function Start () 
   {
       ChangePosition();
       AssignPositions();
   }
   ```
2. I recommend you to change the name of `cubes` to something like `cubesPositions`.
3. The shuffling code blows my mind :D It took me couple of minutes to figure out why it does work. Do you understand how it works yourself?

Comment: @ Sergey Krusch  what is this  blablabla in var cubes: Vector3[] = blablabla; ??

Comment: @ Sergey Krusch  what is this  blablabla in var cubes: Vector3[] = blablabla; ??i consider it as and write it as 

var cubesPosition : Vector3[]  = new Vector3[16];

var cubeGameObjects: GameObject[] = new GameObject[15];

Comment: It means that it's up to you how to fill these arrays. I don't see any code to initialize `cubes` array in your original code. How do you initialize `cubes` with values?

Comment: @ Sergey Krusch please see to the question, i update it. please help me

Comment: Come on, man! 15 cube variables?! :D Just a month ago you had more or less meaningful questions on SO. What has happened with you?

Comment: @  Sergey Krusch me..??? i am noob at unity

okk now help me..i know i am behaving like dump.,but please help me.

Comment: Well, the best you can do now is to get rid of these variables. Use array instead. Unity will show it as a list property in inspector. Also, it's not very clear why you decided to use javascript. You have used Java before, so it makes more sense to use C# for scripting in Unity (but it's up to you).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53864/discussion-between-himani-and-sergey-krusch)